# How to convert String[] to Point for TouchAction command

Tags: java, arrays, string, appium, coordinates

I have a string array of coordinates where each string in the array is assigned to an int

```
String[] A = {"217, 423", "557, 408", "927, 393"};
Random B=new Random();
int randomCoord=B.nextInt(3);
```

I want to be able to plug these coordinates into this command below like so

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.tap(PointOption.point(A[randomCoord])).perform();
```

But when I do that, I get a error that says this

> The method point(Point) in the type PointOption is not applicable for the arguments (String)

So I tried to convert the String to a int like this

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.tap(PointOption.point(Integer.parseInt(A[randomCoord]))).perform();
```

But I got this error

> The method point(int, int) in the type PointOption is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Can anyone help me out? I want the code to plug in a random set of coordinates from the String Array each time I run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you're not getting a NumberFormatException.. but you'll need to parse the random index of A into separate ints

```
    String[] points = A[randomCoord].split(",");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(points[0].trim());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(points[1].trim());
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
    touchAction.tap(PointOption.point(x, y)).perform();
```